# DB2 function Dynamic row as input

Tags: sql, function, dynamic, db2, cursor

I want to create a function in *Db2* like `XMLROW ()`.
E.g. `Select XMLROW (bookname, bookid)` from the book's output.

```
<row>
    <BOOKNAME>the India</BOOKNAME>
    <BOOKID>1</BOOKID>
</row>
```

In this case `XMLROW ()` can take any number of columns as input, regardless of the data type of the column.
Likewise I want to develop a function that takes any column and processes it. I have a problem with the input parameter data type.

Comment: What is your function so far? Share the code and the error

Comment: function is like TO_Json(bookname, bookid ..n) which will convert the selected columns to json regardless of data types and number of columns selected

Comment: @learner_ Can you provide an example of such a function use and results desired? Why isn't the `XMLROW` function suitable for you?

Comment: xmlrow is converting it to xml ... I need json

Comment: Have you checked out the [JSON_OBJECT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070412.html#r0070412) function?

Comment: I have installed db2 express C .. Json_object is not working in it

Comment: You need the latest Db2, either 11.1.4.4 and later or 11.5

Comment: My Db2 version is showing just 11.1 version may be this is  issue . I will proceed with creating a function if I can get solution on above question

Comment: Download Db2 Community Edition  https://www.ibm.com/products/db2-database/developers